# Disable 3D warning overlay

Tags: gaming, nvidia-geforce, 3d

I can't find any way to disable the overlay in the screenshot below from the NVidia control panel.  The biggest pain is that my bluetooth keyboard doesn't have an insert button.
Screenshot: [image]

"This application is not rated by NVIDIA Corp."

**Requested Details:**

- This happens for numerous games
- Windows 8
- Geforce GTX 670mx
- Games operate fine

As for the solution of adding a profile for each unrecognized game, I really don't want to go through all 800+ games in my library :(

Comment: You could still provide more info. what is the game? what is the OS? What is the machine? What is the video card?  And last but not least, does the game continue to operate? So this is just a message you do not need that gets in the way?  Web search says: Create a profile for the specific game with settings and all , and it does not come up again for that game. have you tried that? If that somehow fixes it, please detail it in a self-answer.

Comment: Added requested details

Comment: I did change the toggle hotkey to CTRL+3 so it's at least much easier to dismiss.  Still very annoying.